# C# WebRequest POST and get a specific line - how to display it in label

Tags: c#, post, response, webrequest

here is the picture of it .. look here also /.. http://prntscr.com/5wadok

```
            string fbid = stTextBox1.Text;

            string ukey = stTextBox2.Text;

            string jumlah = "4";


            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "fbid=" + fbid + "&ukey=" + ukey + "&jumlah=" + jumlah; ;
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);


            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://dcvn-full.ga/test/dcgems.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            //MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
            stLabel4.Text = (sr.ReadLine());


            sr.Close();

            stream.Close();
```

I need to read the line21to25 and show it in the stlabel.5 with this command or any other  , can u help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code as follows. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

```
        string fbid = stTextBox1.Text;

        string ukey = stTextBox2.Text;

        string jumlah = "4";


        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "fbid=" + fbid + "&ukey=" + ukey + "&jumlah=" + jumlah; ;
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);


        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://dcvn-full.ga/test/dcgems.php");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            int count=1;
            while(sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                if(count>=21 && count<=25)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(line);
                }
                count++;
                if (count > 25)
                    break;
            }
            stLabel4.Text = (sb.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Change this line to    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();